I cannot understand how is intrinsic rotation really work.
I apologize in advance for my English or stupid question, I am not native speaker. I found good explanation about intrinsic and extrinsic rotation here.
There is an gif example of airplane with intrinsic rotation. If we look to this gif we will understand that axes of the airplane (blue) are moving with airplane and it is the thing that confuse me because when we apply transformation matrix (let's denote this T, from old coordinate system to new) points coordinates change so: $(x_1^{new}, x_2^{new}, ..., x_n^{new}) = T^{-1}(x_1^{old}, x_2^{old},...,x_n^{old})$ and basis changes so: $(e_1^{new}, e_2^{new}, ..., e_n^{new}) = (e_1^{old}, e_2^{old},...,e_n^{old})T$ and that's why new axis shouldn't move with object otherwise what is the point of rotation, but the article says that if we have axis xyz we do first rotation and get new axis x'y'z' (and these axes, in theory, should not be tied to the object), but gif says otherwise. For example, if we take 2D linear space and rotation matrix as rotation to 45 degree counterclockwise the point (1, 0) -> ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$), not (1, 0), but second rotation matrix in article how I understood is applied to coordinate system where point is (1, 0), because in gif the coordinate system moves with object
